# How to add a time picker in handsontable

Tags: angular, handsontable

I want to add time picker in handsontable column I want to just add time picker without date.

But I think it is not supported in handsontable

How do I do that,
I searched for time picker in handsontable but didn't find any

By the way I'm using handsontable in angular 5

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no time picker for Handsontable. Neither official one nor third party plugin. But not everything is lost! It's very easy to create your own editor for Handsontable, there is a detailed tutorial right in the documentation: [Writing Cell Editor Tutorial](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/tutorial-cell-editor.html).

There is also a perfect example in Handsontable source code: [Date Editor](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/blob/master/src/editors/dateEditor.js). It uses third party Pickaday component as a date picker. Should be easy to alter the code to work with any time picker you like.